# Getting the nth value of any STL container and manipulating iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I'm trying to write a function that can do a binary search for any given STL container (i.e lists, vectors, etc). My approach was using two iterators, one for the beginning and end of the sequences.

```
template <class ln, class T> int binarysearch_list(ln first, ln last, T search_value) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = 0;
    int midpoint = 0;
    int start = 0;

    while(first != last) {
        first++;
        start++;
    }
    high = start;

    while(low <= high) {
        ln current = next(first, midpoint);
        if(search_value == *current) {   // if we already find search_value at the midpoint we can simply exit
            return midpoint;
        } else if(search_value > midpoint) {
            low = midpoint + 1; // change the low to the next element after midpoint
        } else if(search_value < midpoint) {
            high = midpoint - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The first while loop is used to get the size, the second one is the actual binary search. I get an error at ln current = next(first, midpoint), I'm not sure how to tackle increment the iterator. Ideally, where you see "if(search_value == *current)" it will act like vector[midpoint] or list(midpoint). I need a way to read the nth element of any given sequence using a begin and end iterator, and I need a way to flexibly increment an iterator by n. I've tried advance(first, amount), (first+amount), and many others but I'm stumped!

Comment: "I'm stumped!" is not a proper error message. Why exactly did `std::advance` not do the right thing?

Comment: Binary search without random access iterators? What's the point?

Comment: Binary search for non-random-access ranges is useless. You have to iterate the range anyways, so you can just as well do a linear search. Binary search will be at most equally good, probably much worse.

Comment: @nwp If I do "ln current = advance(first, midpoint);" I get "error: conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘std::_List_iterator<int>’ requested"

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ideally it will just take the median of (first, last) and start the usual binary search. This is just for practice, I'm not implementing it in a large program

Comment: `ln current = advance(first, midpoint);` is not the correct usage. [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) advances the iterator `first`, it doesn't return an iterator. You would use `current = first; std::advance(current, midpoint);` instead.

Comment: @manni66 — if comparisons are expensive, the smaller number of comparisons done by a binary search can outweigh the linear movements.